# Simple MySQL Table Running Slow Queries

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, myisam

I have a very simple table with two columns, but has 4.5M rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `content_link` (
  `category_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`content_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `content_id` (`content_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

When I run a simple query like:

```
SELECT
    *   
FROM
    content_link
WHERE
    category_id = '11';
```

mysql spikes the CPU and takes 2-5 seconds before returning about 10 rows. The data is spread very evenly across the table and I'm accessing indexed fields (I've also analyzed/optimized the table and I never change the content of the table), so what reason is there for the query to take so long?

Edit: It seems navicat was lying to me and my primary key was not actually keyed in the right order as it was displaying the table to me.

Comment: what do you mean by spread evenly? Is the result correct? Have you profiled the I/O? Is there hardware latency?

Comment: By spread evenly I meant I don't have the ID's clumped together, so a mysql BTREE  index shouldn't have any problems with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`category_id` is not the first column in any index.

Recreate your secondary key as follows:

```
UNIQUE KEY `ix_category_id` (`category_id`, `content_id`)
```

Note the column order, it matters.

Comment: That's really weird. I'm using navicat for table creation, and strangely it shows me the columns in the order I wanted, but apparently this table create query is showing them in a different order.. 

It's actually the primary key that's in the wrong order since I have category id before content_id, they should be keyed in that order.

Answer (score 2):

The UNIQUE KEY ordering is a good solution and you should add a partition strategy to your table too.

By partitioning the table in fragments, MySQL will query the specific partition with the right data set. I've applied and I had excellent results.

```
CREATE TABLE ti (id INT, amount DECIMAL(7,2), tr_date DATE)
ENGINE=INNODB
PARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(tr_date) )
PARTITIONS 6;
```

You need MySQL 5.1.

Try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the index.  When you have a composite index like `(content_id, category_id)`  you can use the index by using `content_id` or you can use `content_id` and `category_id`.  You can't use `category_id` and utilize the index.

Try changing:

```
KEY `content_id` (`content_id`, `category_id`)
```

to

```
KEY `category_id` (`category_id`, `content_id`)
```